# Output the min value for an argument that doesn't crash an R function

Tags: r, function, optimization

**Background:**
Suppose an R function crashes due to a numerically ill-defined argument. I want to catch that crash using `inherit()`. Then, try to use a (perhaps) `while()` loop where I keep changing the input value until the crash doesn't happen! Finally, I want to know what that value was !

**Example:**
Suppose a user inputs `-5` and my function (below) will crash. But **after a crash occurs** could my function **silently** evaluate what the minimum value that would not cause it to crash, is?

```
foo <- function(input) {

  integrate(function(x) qt(.025, x), input, 1e3)[[1]]

}
# Example of crash:
foo(-5)
```

Comment: You wanna have an exception? like telling the user (or not telling them, as you say silently), after the crash, what is the minimum number that they can put in your function?

Comment: Will you clarify then what you exactly want?

Comment: @M-M, could you please let me know what exactly you want to know? What is unclear to you? Suppose an R function crashes due to a numerically ill-defined argument. We catch that crash using `inherit()`. Then we try to use a optimization technique (perhaps) or a `while()` loop where we keep changing the input value until the crash doesn't happen! Finally we output what that value was !

Comment: I left my office. But add content of this comment to Q so it will be a better perceived by others. Good luck.